# how to test class methods with jest (on return values)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Im trying to write unit tests for class methods with `jest` ( new to jest)
I have methods that e.g. take arrays and modify them and bring them into different form to satisfy algorithm needs.
But I dont see a way how I simply can test class method receiving and returning values.
Looks like there is a problem with classes, class methods cant be tested as simple functions.
But if I look at the docs I dont see it covering these topics, it only covers e.g. was a class instance called, was a class method called..

Edited:
this is my code example

```js
import MyClass from "../MyClass.js";

// mocked data
const inputArrayMock=[{someObject}]
const outputArrayMock=[{modifiedObject}]

test("test MyClass method a", () => {
    const obj = new MyClass();
    const result = obj.methodA(inputArrayMock);
    expect(result).toEqual(outputArrayMock);
});
```

I just ran my code again, it's throwing the error:

```js
Received: {Symbol(async_id_symbol): 293, Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 281, Symbol(destroyed): {"destroyed": false}}
```

Note: Both arrays (in- and output values I wrote as mock data. The expected array is correct, but the received not, which throws the error.

Comment: Can you add more detail please?  Can you give an example of the class you're trying to test, the test, and what goes wrong when you try to run the test.  You certainly can test a class method with Jest.

Comment: @MattMorgan Yep, please read the comment I added below the answer suggestion, I added more details there, thanks!

Comment: you should add the clarifying information to the OP, to make it easier for people who see this and might want to help you.  The question itself should contain enough information to make it possible to provide a good answer.

Comment: super late to this, but I discovered that running jest with `detectOpenHandles` will add those properties to Promises.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be async/await related. Again without knowing the class or method your calling, this is just an educated guess.

Try adding async to the test method and call the method with await.

```
import MyClass from "../MyClass.js";

test("your test name", async () => {
    const obj = new MyClass();
    const result = await obj.theMethodYouWantToCheck();
    expect(result).toBe("the desired result");
});
```

This fixed the issue for me. Don't know if its still an issue you're facing, as it's an 8 month old ticket but just for any future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your code I can only make a guess.

```js
import MyClass from "../MyClass.js";

test("your test name", () => {
    const obj = new MyClass();
    const result = obj.theMethodYouWantToCheck();
    expect(result).toBe("the desired result");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So exactly this I tried to do, but it didnt work. Only difference was that I used `toEqual` instead of `toBe` in your example, because I was testing array as input and output. It threw the error, that it expected an array (that I put as expected result), but received {} .